# How can I make my v-container fill all height available?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

So I'm using vuetify 2.0 within my vue.js app and I'm trying to make my v-container in my **Main.vue** to take all the height available using fill-height and fluid but it doesn't seem to work at all.

**What I currently have is looking like this :**

**Screenshot**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWtd9.jpg

> **App.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <div v-if="connected">
            <Main />
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <Login />
        </div>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Main from '@/views/Main'
import Login from '@/views/Login'

  export default {
    components: {
      Main,
      Login
    },
    data: () => ({
      connected: true
    })

  }
</script>
```

> **Main.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-navigation-drawer app clipped dark>
            <v-list>
                <v-list-item link>
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon>mdi-view-dashboard</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>Profil</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
                <v-list-item link>
                    <v-list-item-action>
                        <v-icon>mdi-settings</v-icon>
                    </v-list-item-action>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title>Chat</v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>

        <v-content>
            <v-container class="fill-height"
                         fluid>
                <v-row class="fill-height chat-area" style="background-color: red">
                    <v-col>
                        <p>yooo</p>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>

                <v-row class="text-field-area" style="background-color: green">
                    <v-col>
                        <v-text-field outlined
                                      rounded
                                      label="Type your message"
                                      hide-details
                                      append-icon="mdi-send"
                                      @click :append="logger()"></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
        </v-content>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({}),
        methods: {
            logger() {
                //eslint-disable-next-line
                console.log("Yes tu as cliqué")
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .text-field-area {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 85%;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .chat-area {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 15%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

**What I want to achieve is something like this:**

**Screenshot**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XMo9.jpg

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`fill-height` and, in general, all flexbox related properties rely strictly on parent-child relations.

So when you insert a `<div>` in between the parent and the child, they stop working. To learn more about how flexbox works, I recommend [A complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

In short, your layout:

```
<v-app>
  <div v-if="connected">
    <Main />
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <Login />
  </div>
</v-app>
```

breaks the parent-child relation (between `<v-app>` and `<Main>`).

You can get rid of the extra `<div>`s in two ways:

1. Simply place the `v-if` on the contents:

```html
<v-app>
  <Main v-if="connected" />
  <Login v-else />
</v-app>
```

2. Or use `<template>` tags. Because they're only logical wrappers, Vue doesn't produce actual DOM elements for them. This is particularly helpful when you have multiple elements as content and you don't want to place the `v-if` on each:

```html
<v-app>
  <template v-if="connected">
    <Main />
    <SomeOtherComponent />
    <YetOtherComponent />
  </template>
  <Login v-else />
</v-app>
```

Obviously, if you have more than one component in the `v-else` case, you can turn that into a `<template>` as well.

---

Note of caution: because `<template>` doesn't actually produce a DOM element, when you use it with `v-for`, you'll have to `:key` its children instead of the `<template>`, but except this edge-case, it's a great way to couple layout components without having them wrapped into a DOM element.
It's also useful when you're dealing with strict parent/child HTML relations (i.e: `<table>` + `<tr>` + `<td>`, `<ul>` + `<li>`, `<ol>` + `<li>`, etc...).

Comment: This is one of the most helpful answers I've read on SO thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Here is what is working for me:

```html
<v-container fluid style="height: 100vh;" >
  <v-layout fill-height>
    <!-- content -->
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

Comment: This adds an overflow if you use something like a toolbar ontop.

Answer (score 3):

just set to fill-height to true, like this

```
<v-container fill-height> </v-container>
```

if does not work, put it in v-content, just try this one

```
<v-content>
   <v-container fill-height>
       <v-layout>
            <v-flex xs12>
                    ...
                    ...
            </v-flex>
       </v-layout>
   </v-container>
</v-content>
```

Or

```
<v-content>
    <v-container class="fill-height" fluid>
         <v-row justify="center" align="center">
             <v-col class="shrink">
                  ...
                  ...
            </v-col>
         </v-row>
    </v-container>
</v-content>
```

Comment: I've already tried this one and it does not work (it's in the code I shared), and regarding the second solution,, I'm trying to use the new vuetify grid system https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids#grid-system so I'm avoiding v-layout and v-flew components

Comment: Thank you for help but I've just tried it and it still does not work :(

Comment: maybe because there's a div tag inside your  v-app, remove that and keep the layout like this one. https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/layouts/layouts/demos/complex.vue

Comment: I don't know how to remove it because I can only have one v-app in my whole application (as it should only be used once in an application). I need it in my App.vue, therefore I can't use it in my Main.vue.. I've tried putting everything in one file and removing the div, it works and solves the problem, but as I should have my code separated, I don't know what I'm supposed to do

Comment: I mean remove the div inside of you v-app, basically the pattern should be v-app > v-content > v-container to achieve the your goal

Comment: Yes I get that but I need to use div in order to have some v-else and v-if

Comment: why not just use <Main v-if="connected" />, like that to avoid div tag

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your toolbar and v-main in a div, and set the div's min-height to 100vh.